# How to Use rtrim PHP Function in JAVA

Tags: java, jsp, csv, trim

From a Check box i am getting a array of values.  Here i am looping and getting CSV values like this.  I am trying to remove the last comma in java.  I tried googling and stacking.  I can get some functions it will do this.

```
PHP,JAVA,MYSQL,
```

In PHP we do rtrim('PHP,JAVA,MYSQL,',',');

How to do the same thing in JAVA.  Hope my Question is clear.  Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: How about `String#subString(0,String#length-2)` and just trim it before that.

Comment: I cannot get what are you trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array comes as:

PHP, JAVA, MYSQL,

Then, you have always the last element that is the one that will be removed.

So, then you use:

```
String commaDeleted = yourStringWithComas.subString(0,yourStringWithComas.length - 2);
```

Comment: I assume you mean "length()", the method call, not "length", and "substring" (all lowercase).

Answer (score 0):

You could do a regular expression, using this code from http://www.dzone.com/snippets/remove-space-using-trim-ltrim:

```
String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}
String.prototype.ltrim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+/,"");
}
String.prototype.rtrim = function() {
    return this.replace(/\s+$/,"");
}
```

example:

```
// example of using trim, ltrim, and rtrim
var myString = " hello my name is imdadhusen  ";
alert("*"+myString.trim()+"*");
alert("*"+myString.ltrim()+"*");
alert("*"+myString.rtrim()+"*");
```

EDIT:

Instead of \s you should change it to whatever floats your boat : or create a function with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

`"abcde".substring(0, 4)` returns `"abcd"`